# How do I remove duplicates by max date

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a patient ID, consent of yes or no, and a consent date. There can be more then one consent date and I only want the consents associated with the most recent consent date. In my query below I am having issues on where to put my Group By clause as well as some invalid column names.

```
select CASE_NUM
      ,max(replace(replace(replace(
                convert(varchar(10),convert(datetime,TRCLPLAN.[DATE],112),126)
            ,'-',''),'T',''),':','')
          ) as CONSENT_DATE
      ,case
           when PHOTO_OK = 1
               then 'Y'
           when PHOTO_OK = 2
               then 'N'
           when PHOTO_OK is null
               then 'U'
       end as CONSENT
from
     (select CASE_NUM
            ,max(replace(replace(replace(
                    convert(varchar(10),convert(datetime,TRCLPLAN.[DATE],112),126)
                  ,'-',''),'T',''),':','')
                ) as CONSENT_DATE
            ,case
                 when PHOTO_OK = 1
                     then 'Y'
                 when PHOTO_OK = 2
                     then 'N'
                 when PHOTO_OK is null
                     then 'U'
             end as CONSENT
            ,row_number() over(partition by CASE_NUM order by TRCLPLAN.[DATE] desc) as rn
      from
           CDCLIENT
          inner join TRCLQSC8
              on CDCLIENT.ID = TRCLQSC8.CLIENT_ID
          inner join TRCLPLAN
              on TRCLQSC8.TRT_PLAN_ID = TRCLPLAN.ID
          inner join TRCLQDS3
              on TRCLQSC8.TRT_PLAN_ID = TRCLQDS3.TRT_PLAN_ID
     ) as derivedTable
where derivedTable.rn = 1
--GROUP BY CASE_NUM
--        ,CONSENT
```

Comment: You first need to alias the columns in your sub query so we have some idea which table they come from.  I can guess, but hard to answer without a bunch of back and forth.

Comment: In addition, your question mentions "patient id", "consent", and "consent date".  Yet I see no columns that match those names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  It looks like there are alias that generate the dataset and the question is to `group by` these resulting columns.  You can see `CASE_NUM` which I am assuming is the Patient ID as well as `CONSENT_DATE` and `CONSENT`